# R- how to read in data dynamically

Tags: r, dynamic, load

I'm looking for a solution of not reading in the data statically to R and cannot find a way. 
My aim is to read in data depending on the memory location of the R-Code.
That means not specify the exact path of the data, the only thing which I know about it's memory location is that it is saved in the same file as the code(name will always stay the same). The problem is, that the memory code of this file can change.
Do you have any idea how to solve this or did you have any similar problem?
thanks a lot for your help

c.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand you question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: What "memory codes" are you referring to? Are you trying to read from the memory of a different running program? because most operating systems don't allow that for security reasons. It's very unclear to me exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure that I understand your question entirely.  It would help if you had some code related to an attempt to address the problem.  I also don't have enough points to comment on your post so I have to use the answer feature of stack overflow.

If R isn't provided a full path to a file to read in, it will look for it in the working directory.  You can retrieve your current working directory from within the R console using

```
getwd()
```

and you can change the working directory, either by starting R from a terminal (in linux) while in the directory of interest, or by using

```
setwd(file.path("my","full","or relative","path"))
```

If you always have your script in the same directory as your data or file of interest, then all you ever need to do is make sure that you start R from the directory your files are in and specify the filename only in your read.csv() or file reading command.

I hope this helps.